# Is an "engine bay" fuel pump substantially louder than an "in tank" one?

Tags: fuel-tank, fuel-pump, hood

In the mechanics book I was reading, it says that one of the main reasons that `fuel pumps` were moved from being in the `engine bay` to in the `tank` was because the sound was much more muffled when submerged in gasoline in a separate compartment towards the rear of the car.  This seems logical.

But how much of a difference is it really?  To me, this seems like a pretty minor pro compared to the massive con that is making it much, much harder to diagnose and replace.

**Is it really THAT much louder to have the `fuel pump` in the `engine bay`?**

Comment: I believe the main reason they were put into the fuel tank was two-fold: 1) Electric pumps are submerged in the gasoline so it is easier to pump the fuel, especially at the higher PSI than what was required for carburetors. 2) Being submerged in the gasoline allows for cooling of the pump, which helps them to run longer. I've never heard anything about them moving them to the fuel tank to quiet them down. Most electric fuel pumps you can hear when they kick on if the engine isn't running, but becomes rather subdued when the engine is on.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2.  I'll have to look into the differences in power consumption, as well as ways to keep a pump cool while in the engine bay.  Those may really be the true hurdles.

Comment: It's really not hard to diagnose and replace in-tank fuel pumps, they are typically accessed by lifting the rear seat.

Comment: I've never had the luck of a car where that was true